# Query analysing tool

Tags: jquery, optimization

Suppose there are 10 joins in a query and i want to find which join is taking long to fetch the data is there any tool to get that report ?

Comment: If you're using MySQL you could use `EXPLAIN your_query_here` to see what's happening during query...

Comment: Marco this was one of the interview question which i was not able to answer properly so i thought i could get help of friends on stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) One method is to save the time before and after the query and to calculate
the difference, something like this:

```
DECLARE @start_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME
SET @start_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

-- query goes here

SET @end_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @start_time, @end_time)

You can also use something like this to see the execution time in the
Messages tab:

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

-- query goes here

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

2)running SQL Profiler trace

3)analysing the Execution Plan